# I have unknown Margin popping up at the end of my container in flexbox even though I have 0 margin

Tags: html, css, margin

I have some mystery `Margin` popping up at the end of my **.container_main** in my Inspect on Google Chrome. My margin is set to 0 but there is still some margin that is preventing me from flex-ending my content. Please let me know what you think!

Here is my code and I will also attach an image of my inspect panel.

```
/* Box Model Hack */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

/* Clear fix hack */
.clearfix:after {
     content: ".";
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     line-height: 0;
     height: 0;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

/******************************************
/* MAIN LAYOUT
/*******************************************/

/******************************************
/* NAVBAR
/*******************************************/

nav{
  height: 65px;
  background-color: rgba(245,249,252,255)
}
.container_nav{
  max-width: 1750px;
  background-color: rgba(245,249,252,255)
}
nav .container_nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.container_nav a{
  padding: 0 0 0 2rem;
}
button{
  width: 80px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: rgb(47, 70, 88);
  border: none;
  color: white;
}

/******************************************
/* MAIN
/*******************************************/
main{
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: aqua;
}
.left{
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  height: 35rem;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  padding: 2rem;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
.left span{
  color: rgba(150,167,183,255);
}
.right{
  display: flex;
  background-color: orange;
}
.container_main{
  max-width: 1750px;
  margin: 0%;
}
main .container_main{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}



/******************************************
/* GENERAL STYLES
/*******************************************/
li{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container_nav .first{
  padding: 0;
}
ul{
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Margin even though there isn't any.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrR0R.png)

Comment: That's not margin. That's probably overflowing content due to the max-width. Try setting main to 100% width. Hard to tell definitely without working example.

Comment: It was a max-width issue! Setting the width didn't fix it but removing the max-width did. If you want to comment officially I can upvote you lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to the help of niorad.

It was my max-width. When I removed it solved my problem and everything worked just fine!